# How to add Average into subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I tried a nested subquery to join three tables together to get the columns needed.

```
SELECT CAPACITY, Course.COURSE_NAME, SEMESTER
FROM COURSE, Section, Room
WHERE Section.COURSE_NUM
IN (SELECT Course.COURSE_NUMBER
  FROM Course
  WHERE SEMESTER='FALL' AND Section.ROOM
  IN (SELECT Room.ROOM
    FROM Room
    WHERE AVG(CAPACITY)>CAPACITY
  )
)
```

I had it all right before the second subquery I just need the Column capacity to display results greater then the average of the column. So this was the output before the nested subquery.

```
SELECT CAPACITY, Course.COURSE_NAME, SEMESTER
FROM COURSE, Section, Room
WHERE Section.COURSE_NUM
IN (SELECT Course.COURSE_NUMBER
  FROM Course
  WHERE SEMESTER='FALL'
)
```

I just need to be able to display the Column Capacity results that are greater then its average number.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell by this that which table has the Capacity column and what is the relationship between the tables you have there, but all i can say is that you need to join the 3 tables again in the subquery to be able to access the Capacity there, somthing like this:

```
SELECT CAPACITY, Course.COURSE_NAME, SEMESTER
FROM COURSE, Section, Room
WHERE Section.COURSE_NUM
IN (SELECT Course.COURSE_NUMBER
FROM Course
WHERE SEMESTER='FALL' AND Section.ROOM
        IN(
           SELECT Room.ROOM
           FROM Room
           INNER JOIN SEMESTER
              ON COLUMNS
           INNER JOIN SECTION
              ON COLUMNS
           INNER JOIN COURSE
              ON COLUMNS
           WHERE AVG(CAPACITY)>CAPACITY
           )
```

Comment: Capacity is in ROOM. Semester comes from Section, and COURSE_NAME comes from COURSE.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to be able to figure it out.

```
SELECT CAPACITY, Course.COURSE_NAME, SEMESTER
FROM COURSE, Section, Room
WHERE Section.COURSE_NUM
IN (SELECT Course.COURSE_NUMBER
FROM COURSE
WHERE SEMESTER='FALL' AND Room.ROOM
IN (SELECT Section.ROOM
FROM Section
WHERE CAPACITY>(SELECT AVG(CAPACITY) FROM Room)))
ORDER BY CAPACITY
```